# Presenting UIImagePickerController crashes app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to present a UIImagePickerController via a Button action. My project crashes with error:

> Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
>   a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
>   used by your application.

I only have a ViewController embedded in a NavigationController in the storyboard. Code snippets below:

```
UIImagePickerController imagePicker;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    this.setupImagePicker();

    CapturePhotoButton.TouchUpInside += delegate
    {
        this.AddMedia();
    };
}

public void setupImagePicker()
{
    imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
    imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
    imagePicker.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
    imagePicker.MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera);
    imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += HandleFinishedPickingMedia;
    imagePicker.Canceled += (sender, e) => {
        imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
    };
}

public void HandleFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, 
    UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isImage = false;

    switch (e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString())
    {
        case "public.image":
            isImage = true;
            break;
        case "public.video":
            break;
    }

    if (isImage)
    {
        UIImage originalImage = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;
        if (originalImage != null)
        {
            PreviewImageView.Image = originalImage;
            imagePicker.DismissViewController(true, null);
        }
    }
}

public void AddMedia()
{
    //Crashes on this line
    this.NavigationController.PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, null);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the ViewController itself have a PresentViewController method? Could you try use that to see if that does any difference? `this.PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, null);`

Comment: tried that as well and it still crashes on the presentation

Comment: Did you give that a go as well ? @Cheesebaron

Comment: I have it working fine in my apps. Not sure what is wrong in yours. Can you try removing the `ModalPresentationStyle` and `MediaTypes`. I don't use them.

Comment: not sure either, perhaps it's something trivial ? I've tried removing ModalPresentationStyle and MediaTypes but still doesn't work. Also this is tested on iOS 10.

Comment: Did you add `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app uses photos</string>` to your info.plist?

Answer (score 3):

Added Privacy - Camera Usage Description to your info.plist and that resolved the issue

Comment: Exact same problem, and this fixed it. I'm surprised the iTunes Connect analysis of the app doesn't catch this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your info.plist for camera use:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
```

for library:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
```